# Apache Derby DB returns syntax error on "PARTITION"

Tags: sql, database, apache, derby

When trying to use "PARTITION BY" on derbyDB, I get refused for "Syntax Error": Encountered "PARTITION".

I am trying to SELECT data, defining the following column:

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS ROW_NUM FROM TABLE`

I also checked the documentations on:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/OLAPOperations

But get refused by derbyDB on "Syntax error: Encountered 'PARTITION'"

I expect derbyDB to support partitioning by as shown on the documentation and to select and display the row numbers.

Comment: Correct. Apache Derby does not implement the OLAP extensions to SQL. That wiki page that you found is from a development proposal that was never implemented.